# This is a linearSearch code. Instead of returning true how can I return the position of that value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-search

```
def main():
  testList = [3, 1, 8, 1, 5, 2, 21, 13]
  print("searching for 5 in", testList,"...")
  searchResult1 = linearSearch(testList, 5)
  print(searchResult1)


def linearSearch(aList, target):
  for item in aList:
    if item == target:
      return True

  return False



main()
```

Instead of returning true if the value is in the list, how can I return the position of that value?

Comment: what happen when you encounter duplicates target values, what you want then ? `aList.index(target)` works if you want first occurence index

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the index of an item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list)

Comment: Wait, why did you edit the code? The question doesn't make any sense anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Use `list.index()`:

```
>>> testList = [3, 1, 8, 1, 5, 2, 21, 13]
>>> testList.index(5)
4
>>> testList.index(16)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 16 is not in list
```

By the way, for checking membership, use `in`:

```
>>> 5 in testList
True
>>> 16 in testList
False
```

Docs: [Common Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)

Comment: @ivanlin2020 What do you mean?

Comment: So it should return that position of the number and the number could change

Comment: @ivanlin2020 I'm still not sure what you mean. Could you give an example?

Comment: For my code I want it to return the position, you see how it returns true and false, ya I want to return the position instead

Comment: Yes, that's what my answer explains how to do...?

Comment: I want it to find the position depending on what value is given. Your code only finds the position of 5

Comment: @ivanlin2020 5 is the value that is given, so you just need to replace it

Comment: Hey so your code works but if you try to find the position of a number thats not in the list it gives an error. I would rather return false

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your code entirely, you can use enumerate for getting index position.

```py
def linearSearch(aList, target):
  for ix, item in enumerate(aList):
    if item == target:
      return ix
  return False
```

Comment: Returning `False` is questionable because `False == 0`.

Comment: @ivanlin2020 wants to get rid of the "True" response. There is no comment about "False" response.

Comment: I know, I'm saying that you should return something other than `False` if the value is not found, because `0` is a possible index, and `False == 0`. For example, `linearSearch(testList, 3)` -> `0`; `linearSearch(testList, 16)` -> `False`. As a fix, you could use `-1`, like `str.find()`.